# How to solve $\mathrm{cot}(2x)=\frac {-7}{6}?$

Tags: trigonometry

This has been bothering me for a while now.

$\mathrm{cot}(2x)=\frac{-7}{6}$

How do I solve for an angle x in a double angle situation such as this? I honestly don't even know where to start.

Trying anything at one point, I thought I could rearrange to get $\tan(2x)$ then apply $\mathrm{arctan}$ and divide by $2$ but that doesn't work.

The angle $x$ is supposed to be $69.7$ degrees from the solutions I'm working with.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your approach seems sensible - what went wrong?

Comment: Well I get to tan(2x)=-6/7 which gives me an angle of 81.2 degrees which is wrong apparently

Comment: Include the working in your post, so we can spot the mistake: $\tan(2x)=-6/7$ is a correct first step

Comment: The tangent of an acute angle is positive. For a negative tangent you need an obtuse angle (or the negative of an acute angle). @Davin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\tan(2x)=-\frac{6}{7}$$
If you just take the arctan, you get $-40.6^\circ$. Note that the tangent function has a periodicity of $180^\circ$, so you can use $2x=180^\circ-40.6^\circ=139.4^\circ$, which yields $x=69.7^\circ$

Comment: Ah got it - hadn't even considered periodicity... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$ \cot (2x) = -7/6$$

$$ \tan (2x) = -6/7$$

$$ 2x= \tan ^{-1} (-6/7)$$

$$x= (1/2) \tan ^{-1} (-6/7)\approx -20.30 $$degrees

For a positive solution you may add 90 degrees to get

$$  x= (1/2) \tan ^{-1} (-6/7) + 90 \approx  69.69 $$degrees

Comment: This gives a negative result. The OP says the answer is supposed to be positive.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited my solution.